# Excel Break Links not Working - Links *not hidden*

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I've a spreadsheet that links to two others for hundreds of formulas.  When I open this spreadsheet, certain formulas, which are summing from tables in never show values unless the source spreadsheets are open.  Hence, to share this spreadsheet with other users, I have to break the links.  No problem.

But there is a problem.  No matter how many times I break links, I see formulas that still reference the external sheets.  Even formulas that are simple "=[source]sheet!cell"; on the same tab, some have been replaced by the values and others have not.

All I can find on the internet about non-functioning link breaking is because the users can't find the links.  I see the formulas, just Excel is not breaking them.

Any ideas?

Comment: It could also be that the model contains links in the conditional formatting to an external file. Excel break links function is not able to change this (sadly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had no responses on SO, and while continuing to research I found the issue.  As I said, when I tried to break links, some of them were broken, but other cells did not have the links replaced in their formulas.

When I went in and removed the named ranges referencing the source spreadsheets - that I was fully aware were there - the problem was resolved.  After removal of the names, when I told Excel to break the links, **all** formulas with external links were replace.

Hence, Excel would essentially begin to break the links, then get hung up on something related to the named ranges, and give up.  It should be obvious that this is extremely different than the usually-reported link breaking issue (links in formulas are all broken; user is unaware of other links).